# Find the furthest distance of points

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, spatial

In this scenario I have a set of four points for ID 1 and 2. I need to find and select the two points that are furthest from my set points with the same ID.

The table is scripted here:

```
ID  name    point                                           id_point
====================================================================
1   DN700   POINT (-550493.96 -1218974.69)                  1
1   DN700   POINT (-550513.92733318976 -1218929.5493905835) 2
1   DN700   POINT (-550490.62291509821 -1218980.7209425652) 3
1   DN700   POINT (-550512.43436134933 -1218933.2777663434) 4
2   DN700   POINT (-550235.5039543492 -1219120.0737476321)  5
2   DN700   POINT (-550278.61165674869 -1219099.6880138929) 6
2   DN700   POINT (-550301.89265282557 -1219088.8117909778) 7
2   DN700   POINT (-550330.76399739366 -1219075.4882849427) 8
```

For **ID** 1, the farthest points are **id_point** 2 and 3. I will use it in another procedure, where I have to define the start and end point, which in this case is exactly point 2 and 3.

I know the solution is to use the **STDistance()** function to compare points with the same ID, then select a **MAX value** from the result, but I'm stuck here.

Any help is appreciated, thanks a lot!

Here is an sample of my query, which I describe in the comments. The **#points_on_lin** is a table which I previously scripted in question. The only difference is that the points are stored as geometry:

```
DECLARE @max_id int, @current_id int = 1;
SET @max_id = (SELECT MAX(ID_point) FROM #points_on_lin)
    WHILE @current_id <= @max_id
        BEGIN
            DECLARE @point1 geometry, @point2 geometry, @ID int, @IDP int;
            SET @point1 = (SELECT points FROM #points_on_lin WHERE ID_point = @current_id)
            SET @point2 = (SELECT points FROM #points_on_lin WHERE ID_point = @current_id + 1)
            SET @ID = (SELECT ID FROM #points_on_linia WHERE ID_point = @current_id)
            SET @name = (SELECT name FROM #points_on_lin WHERE ID_point = @current_id)
            SET @IDP = (SELECT ID_point FROM #points_on_lin WHERE ID_point = @current_id)
                INSERT INTO #points_dist
                    SELECT @ID, @name, @point1.STDistance(@point2), @IDP
            SET @current_ID = @current_ID +1
        END
```

And the results from table **#points_dist** are here:

```
ID  name    distance            IDP
1   DN700   49.3595888677907    1
1   DN700   56.228317019116     2
1   DN700   52.216799572342     3
1   DN700   334.040699536517    4
2   DN700   47.6849257758674    5
2   DN700   25.696244924673     6
2   DN700   31.7973324390265    7
2   DN700   544.411492523736    8
```

Comment: So what was your attempt when you tried to implement `STDistance` and `MAX`? Why didn't it work?

Comment: @Larnu Using these points, I created an iteration with ID 1, but only from one id_point to the next point. So I only get back the distance from one to the other. However, I have to choose the farthest points, which in this case are id_point 2 and 3, but the maximum value in my distance calculation is at point 4, which means that the farthest distance is from 3 to 4. And of course it's wrong. Now I don't know what to do next. Create an iteration from one point to other points with the same ID and then select the maximum value for ID 1? Hmm maybe that is a right way :/

Comment: Put your attempt in the question though. Use the [edit] feature.

Comment: @Roman Can you add your data and table script?

Comment: Okay, I've edited my question, you can look at it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT ID FROM #points_on_lin GROUP BY ID
)
SELECT CTE.ID, Point1, Point2, Distance FROM CTE
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT TOP 1 
        T1.id_point AS Point1, T2.id_point AS Point2, T1.Point.STDistance(T2.Point) AS Distance 
    FROM 
        #points_on_lin T1 join #points_on_lin T2 on T1.ID = T2.ID AND T1.id_point < T2.id_point
    WHERE 
        T1.ID = CTE.ID
    ORDER BY
        Distance DESC   
) A
```

Output:

```
ID  Point1  Point2  Distance
1   2       3       56.228317019116
2   5       8       105.177655821281
```

Comment: That's exactly what was I looking for ! Thanks a lot @hsn !!

Answer (score 0):

I did this:

```
create table #MainTable
(
    id int,
    name nvarchar(10),
    point nvarchar(max),    
    id_point int
)

insert into #MainTable
values
        (1 ,'DN700','POINT (-550493.96 -1218974.69)' ,1),
        (1 ,'DN700','POINT (-550513.92733318976 -1218929.5493905835)' ,2),
        (1 ,'DN700','POINT (-550490.62291509821 -1218980.7209425652)' ,3),
        (1 ,'DN700','POINT (-550512.43436134933 -1218933.2777663434)' ,4),
        (2 ,'DN700','POINT (-550235.5039543492 -1219120.0737476321)' ,5),
        (2 ,'DN700','POINT (-550278.61165674869 -1219099.6880138929)' ,6),
        (2 ,'DN700','POINT (-550301.89265282557 -1219088.8117909778)' ,7),
        (2 ,'DN700','POINT (-550330.76399739366 -1219075.4882849427)' ,8)

create table #Result
(
    id int,
    name nvarchar(10),
    distance float,
    id_point int 
)

declare @minId as int=(select min(id) from #MainTable)
declare @maxId as int=(select max(id) from #MainTable)
declare @p1 as int=0
declare @p2 as int=0
DECLARE @point1 geometry, @point2 geometry
declare @Distance as float=0

while @minId<=@maxId
    begin
        set @p1=(select min(id_point) from #MainTable where id=@minId)
        set @p2=(select max(id_point) from #MainTable where id=@minId)
        while @p1<@p2
            begin
                set @point1=(select geometry::STGeomFromText(point,0) from #MainTable where id_point=@p1)
                set @point2=(select geometry::STGeomFromText(point,0) from #MainTable where id_point=@p1+1)
                set @Distance=@point1.STDistance(@point2)
                insert into #Result (id,name,distance,id_point)
                select id,name,@Distance,@p1 from #MainTable where id_point=@p1

                insert into #Result (id,name,distance,id_point)
                select id,name,@Distance,@p1+1 from #MainTable where id_point=@p1+1
                set @p1=@p1+1
            end     
        set @minId=@minId+1
    end

select r1.* 
from #Result r1 
inner join (select id,max(distance)maxDistance
            from #Result
            group by id)r2 on r1.id=r2.id
                                and r1.distance=r2.maxDistance
order by id

drop table #MainTable,#Result
```

and here is the result:
[Result of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1njdR.png)

hope it's helpfull.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The values ​​for the first ID are correct, but the second is incorrect. The correct ID_point is 5 and 8. Thanks for your solution, but I'm going with the answer @hsn in this!